# How to add expression on wso2 esb foreach mediator when request is text

Tags: foreach, wso2-esb

I used wso2 foreach mediator. When my request is Json then I added "//data" as expression.

> foreach expression="//data"

my json request is like this

```
{  
  "data":[ 
  {  
     "id":1,
     "name":"abc",
  },
  {  
     "id":2,
     "name":"efg",
  }
 ]
}
```

This scenario worked as fine. Now I need to send like this **"pri,23,aaaa;nuwa,45,qqqq"** text value as request.Question is,

> **how I set expression in foreach tag when request is text valu**

Answer (score 1):

ForEach mediator only support XML and JSON content types. Your message is a CSV, and hence I suggest you convert it to XML and then use ForEach mediator.