# Script mediator with for loop in wso2 esb

Tags: javascript, for-loop, wso2-esb

I tried to use for loop inside the script mediator.
Here is my attempt

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
            var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];

            var i;
            var text = "";
            for(i=0 ; i< cars.length;i++){
                text+ = array[i]+ "<br>";

            }
        ]]></script>
```

But when I going to save this It show error. But when I remove for loop its work fine. What is the wrong. Can't I add for loop inside script mediator.

Then otherwise I tried to use foreach mediator.There also have some [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718783/how-to-add-expression-on-wso2-esb-foreach-mediator-when-request-is-text) with me.How can I solve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space between + and = which is a syntax error because you can't have a + in the variable name.

The line should read:

`text += array[i]+ "<br>";`